# CA API Gateway XML List Response to Json

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xpath, api-gateway

I have a problem with converting my response XML to Json in CA API Gateway.

My xml like ;

```
           <Result>
               <MetaDataItem>
                  <ComponentType>TEXTBOX</ComponentType>
                  <DataType>System.String</DataType>
               </MetaDataItem>
               <MetaDataItem>
                  <ComponentType>DATETIME</ComponentType>
                  <DataType>System.String</DataType>
               </MetaDataItem>
           <Result>
```

When I try to get the inner child elements with xpath;
[image]
The response is like;

```
{
    "result":{
        "resultCode":"1000",
        "resultMessage":""
        "result":"TEXTBOXSystem.StringDATETIMESystem.String,
     }
}
```

It just returns just the first MetaDataItems values as string.I can not convert this result string into a json.

I want result json like;

```
"MetaDataItem": [
            {
                "ComponentType":"TEXTBOX",
                "DataType" : "System.String"
            }
           ,{
                "ComponentType":"DATETIME",
                "DataType" : "System.String"
            }
            
        ]
```

Are there anyone who get the idea for CA API Gateway XML to JSON transformation?

Comment: So which other XPath versions can you select in the "XPath Version" select box?

Comment: @MartinHonnen the selected xpath version is **1.0** . The select box has **1.0** and **2.0** options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that environment but if all you have is XPath 2.0 then

```
concat('[', 
       string-join(
           for $item in //MetaDataItem 
           return concat('{', string-join(for $c in $item/* return concat('"', local-name($c), '":"', $c ,'"'), ', '), '}'), ', '), ']')
```

as the XPath 2.0 expression should give the string `[{"ComponentType":"TEXTBOX", "DataType":"System.String"}, {"ComponentType":"DATETIME", "DataType":"System.String"}]`, perhaps if you additionally set the "variable prefix" to `MetaDataItem` the result is closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks!! that was what i am looking for  :)